# Segmentation fault while using google test

Tags: c++, c, googletest

I am passing a compound structure pointer to a function after doing all the memory initialization in a test fixture. But as soon as the function gets called the `sizeof` that struct changes.

Have tried setting watchpoints and  everything. Don't know what's the issue.

This is the code for the test.

```
TEST(testMib1, test)
{

        CwRrcUeCb* ueCb;
        CW_ALLOC(CW_REG,CW_POOL,&ueCb, sizeof(CwRrcUeCb));
        memset(ueCb, 0, sizeof(CwRrcUeCb));
        ueCb->currContestCellForSel = (CwRrcCellCb *) 
        malloc(sizeof(CwRrcCellCb));
        ueCb->currContestCellForSel->phyCellId = 5;
        ueCb->ueId = 5;
        S16 ret = ROK;

        ret = cwRrcSendMibCfgReq(ueCb);

        CW_FREE(CW_REG, CW_POOL, ueCb, sizeof (CwRrcUeCb));
        free(ueCb->currContestCellForSel);
        EXPECT_EQ(ROK, ret);
        printf(" Event 9 Done\n\n\n");
}
```

`sizeof(*ueCb)` changes just after calling the function `cwRrcSendMibCfgReq`.
The function is copying some parameters from `ueCb`. `ueCb` has multiple structures inside of it. Accessing `ueCb->currContestCellForSel` in the function throws a segmentation fault even though I have explicitly allocated memory here. I have checked that the allocation occurs.

Comment: sizeof is determined at compile time. Are you building the test and the main code with different .h files?

Comment: Welcome at stackoverflow please read [ask] before posting new questions.

Comment: _sizeof that struct changes_ ....... Post your code and elaborate a little bit about this point...

Comment: I still think the issue is that you're building the test code and the main code with different struct definitions. Can you use your IDE to 'navigate to declaration' or similar for the struct, from inside both the test project and the main project code, to make sure it's the same place? Are there any #ifdefs in the definition that might be different between the two?

Comment: There is only one struct definition and we aren't using any IDE. Going the old way but have seen there is only on struct definition.